# How to read data contained in the _metadata of a javascript array

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am querying a Sharepoint 2013 List using the REST api. I copy the results into a javascript array.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Lxs.jpg)

I assign one of the objects in the array to a variable:

var fintname = tempArray[0];

When I use the debugger to look at the contents of fintname I see (please see attached pic):

Please look at the items listed under the _metadata node.

I need to access (read) the 'id' and 'type' properties that are under the _metadata tag, but I cannot seem to be able to access these values.

fintname._metadata is 'undefined'... I am not sure what I am missing here.

Could someone shed some light into how to access (read) these properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting some I finally found the solution: I had to look at the object keys to get to the properties I needed. The following snippet of code shows how it's done:

```
for(var key in fintname)
{
   var myKey = fintname[key];
   console.log("id: " + myKey.id);
   console.log("type: " + myKey.type);
}
```